# Python GroupBy sort Descending by column within grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, group-by

I have a dataset with the following columns - ID, Old Stage, New Stage and Cycle Number.
Each ID has multiple rows (2+), depicting a series of back and forth between old and new stage; this is detailed by the Cycle Number.

I am trying to group multiple rows by ID (that's ok), but within that grouping I want to sort by Cycle Number. For e.g. if ID 1 has 6 cycles, I want cycle #6 to be listed first, then 5, 4, 3, etc.

```
grouped2 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Old_Stage', 'New_Stage'], as_index=False)['Cycle_Number'].max().sort_values(['Cycle_Number'], ascending=False)
print(grouped2)
```

This is what I tried, however, it only sorts the Cycle Numbers in descending order overall, not **within the ID grouping**.

**EDIT**

Current dataframe:

```
|ID |Old Stage   |New Stage   |Cycle Number|
|100|In Progress |Under Review|1
|100|Not Started |In Progress |0
|100|Under Review|Completed   |2
|100|Completed   |In Progress |3
```

Desired dataframe:

```
|ID |Old Stage   |New Stage   |Cycle Number|
|100|Completed   |In Progress |3
|   |Under Review|Completed   |2
|   |In Progress |Under Review|1
|   |Not Started |In Progress |0
```

Comment: please provide an example of the original dataset and the expected output.

Comment: better create example data as `DataFrame(...)` so we could test it and see problem.

Comment: why do you use `['Cycle_Number'].max()` ?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with groups by you could sort before grouping - `df.sort_values(by=['ID','Cycle'], ascending=[True,False])`

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your responses - I've edited the above query with the current DF and desired. @furas, I used .max() to get the highest Cycle Number per ID

Comment: Can you explian why `df.sort_values(by=['ID','Cycle'], ascending=[True,False])` not working here? It should be correct.

Comment: It doesn't keep it grouped by ID

Comment: I tested `df.sort_values(by=['ID','Cycle'], ascending=[True,False])` and it displays in correct order and later `groupby('ID')` also keeps order in groups. I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe create minimal working code with example data in code (as 'DtatFrame(...)`)

Answer (score 0):

As [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71604402/python-groupby-sort-descending-by-column-within-grouping#comment126556215_71604402) and [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71604402/python-groupby-sort-descending-by-column-within-grouping#comment126570220_71604402) mentioned, using [`pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), as follows, should solve OP's problem

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'Cycle Number'], ascending=[True, False])

[Out]:
    ID     Old Stage     New Stage  Cycle Number
3  100     Completed   In Progress             3
2  100  Under Review     Completed             2
0  100   In Progress  Under Review             1
1  100   Not Started   In Progress             0
```

However, OP mentioned

> It doesn't keep it grouped by ID

It seems that OP is referring to the order of the index. As one can see on the output of the previous dataframe, it goes from 3, to 2, to 0, to 1, and, IIUC, OP wants it going from 0 to 1, to 2, and so on.

If that is the case, what is missing is just `.reset_index(drop=True)` as follows

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'Cycle Number'], ascending=[True, False]).reset_index(drop=True)

[Out]:
    ID     Old Stage     New Stage  Cycle Number
0  100     Completed   In Progress             3
1  100  Under Review     Completed             2
2  100   In Progress  Under Review             1
3  100   Not Started   In Progress             0
```